# I need to compare the answer student selected against the correct answer and give a point

Tags: laravel

I have two tables question and answer, question table has field question name, options ans and point and answer table has question ID and answer field

I need if a student select an answer first to be compared with the correct answer and give him/her a point given to that question if it is correct, and if the answer given by a student does not match with the correct answer then the marks should be zero, Thereafter I need to  get total score against the total marks of the quiz.
[image: Image of what i need]

```
$results=Answers::all();
$qns = Questions::all();

$answers = DB::table('answers')->select('answer')->get();
$ans = DB::table('questions')->select('id','ans')->get();
$point = DB::table('questions')->select('point')->get();

if ($answers == $ans && $id == $question_id) {
    echo $point;
} else {
    echo $point=0;
}

return view('test.result')->with('results',$results)->with('qns', $qns);
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic example to solve your problem

```
$results=Answers::all();
$qns = Questions::all();
$point = 0;
foreach($qns as $key => $value){

    if ($results[$key]->answer == $value->correct_answer) {
        $point += $value->point;
    }
}
echo $point;
```

Now you have to workaround in your way to achieve your desired result.

Comment: hasan  emon, i tried you code it did not work the way i was expecting, I have attached the image of what i need, from the image the first question the answer is wrong so a need a marks column to be zero and the second question is correct so i need it to pick the mark point given to it, at the moment it has just retrieved a mark point but it has not checked on it

Comment: You can do it on client side. You have to play around to get the desired result.

Comment: hasan i have not figure out can you help me please